# Sharing user object across javascript screens using Springframework MVC

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-mvc

I asked a question earlier how to do this using Webflow, but it has proven to be impractical for my situation.

I am trying to have a walk through 3 screens which add to an object information and then require a confirm to add to the database at the end. [To maintain simplicity etc]

The first screen takes in username for example
then the next screen requires contact information
then the third screen shows a summary and asks to confirm

I am having trouble figuring out how to pass the same object through several screens. I understand how to pass information from one screen to next, but for some reason same technique doesn’t work through several screens.

Sample 3 pages:

**AddUser.jsp**

```
<div id="form">
<h2 >Step 1</h2>
    <form action="AddUserContact" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>User Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="username" name="username"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Next"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

**AddUserContact.jsp**

```
<div id="form">
<h2 >Step 2</h2>
    <form action="UserSummaryConfirm" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>${user.username}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Address:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="address" name="address"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Next"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

**UserSummaryConfirm.jsp**

```
<h2>Step 3</h2>
    <form action="home" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>User Name:</td>
                <td>${user.username}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Address:</td>
                <td>${address}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="home">Confirm</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

I have a Controller for every page [its for me to understand better what is going on, Ill simplify it later]

**AddUserController.java**

```
@Controller
public class AddUserController{
@RequestMapping(value = "AddUser")
    public ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    User user = new User();
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("AddUser");
    user.setUserName(request.getParameter("username"));
    mav.addObject("user", user);
    return mav;
    }
}
```

**AddUserContactController.java**

```
@Controller
public class AddUserContactController{
@RequestMapping(value = "AddUserContact")
    public ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("AddUserContact");
        mav.addObject("user", request.getParameter("user"));
        return mav;
       }
  }
```

**AddUserConfirm.java**

```
@Controller
public class AddUserConfirm{
    @RequestMapping(value = "UserSummaryConfirm")
    public ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("UserSummaryConfirm");
        mav.addObject("user", request.getParameter("user"));
        mav.addObject("address", request.getParameter("address"));
        return mav;
    }
}
```

And then the User class is just a simple class with getters and setters.
The problem I am having is no matter what I have tried to pass the object, I cannot seem to figure out why the same technique doesnt work.

The address on the third screen is beeing displayed no problem, but the username is not displayed on any of the screens.

With the webflow the way I did it was created a UserBean that was global to all webflow screens. It was easy to add to the same object from any screen and display any information. How can I achieve the same result for this?

Thank you.

WORKING CODE:

Using SessionAttributes

**AddUser.jsp**

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<div id="form">
<h2 >Step 1</h2>
    <form:form action="AddUserContact" commandName="user" method="POST">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>User Name:</td>
                <td><form:input type="text" id="username" path="username"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Next"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
</div>
```

**AssUserContact.jsp**

```
<div id="form">
<h2 >Step 2</h2>
    <form:form action="UserSummaryConfirm" commandName="user" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Address:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="address" path="address"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Next"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

**UserSummaryConfirm.jsp**

```
<h2>Step 3</h2>
    <form:form action="home" method="get">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>User Name:</td>
                <td><%=session.getAttribute("username")%></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Address:</td>
                <td><%=session.getAttribute("address")%></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="home">Confirm</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
```

**AddUserController.java**

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes({ "username", "address" })
public class AddUserController{
    User usr = new User();    

@RequestMapping(value = "AddUser")
   public String loadIndex(Model model, User user) {
    model.addAttribute("User", user);
    return "AddUser";
    }

@RequestMapping(value = "AddUserContact")
public String processUserName(Model model, User user) {
usr.setUsername(user.setUsername());
model.addAttribute("User", user);
return "AddUserContact";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "UserSummaryConfirm")
public String processUserContact(Model model, User user) {
usr.setAddress(user.getAddress());
model.addAttribute("username", usr.getUsername());
model.addAttribute("address", usr.getAddress());
return "UserSummaryConfirm";
    }
```

Comment: While I haven't used it, it seems like this is exactly what Spring Webflow was made for... http://www.springsource.org/spring-web-flow

Comment: I used webflow for this exact situation where a user bean was shared across the flow. I want to make it work in MVC because there isnt actually that much support for Webflow currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in second screen you are using

```
    <tr>
        <td>${user.username}</td>
    </tr>
```

User input is not bind to any input so it will not be passed to controller with form data .
While you are using address as

```
    <tr>
        <td>Address:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="address" name="address"/></td>
    </tr>
```

As it is bind to input (as you have assigned `name="address"` which is same as `path="name"`) so its value will be send to controller.

If you want to pass the same object across 3 screens then it's better use [@SessionAttribute](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/spring/session-attributes-annotation.html) instead of hiding it and passing again and again.

---

**EDIT :**

As you are using session attribute now, remove input element .(which is bind to username) from second screen. Just use instead

```
   <td>session.getAttribute("username")%></td>
```

Comment: I tried doing something like <input type="hidden" id="user" name="${user}"/> to pass it through the second screen, but it didnt help either, could you suggest of a better way?

Comment: sorry cannot edit that, it ment to say instead of name, value="${user}"

Comment: @Sheogora: You should add `name` attribute or better use sessionaAttribute.

Comment: It helped to an extent, I noticed using Session Attribute, that during the first screen when you add username the form creates the object specific to the form and then passes through controller, this value can then be retrieved on the next screen through session call. When you use the same object as part of the form on the second screen, it doesnt input the username again, I had to add an input field to pass the value to the third screen. I think my other option is to have another class to represent both forms (screen1 and screen2) or am I doing something wrong? I will add an EDIt soon

Comment: I would appreciate if you could check the edit of the code I made, it is the current code I tried working with using SessionAttributes. Thank you.

Comment: Hello, putting in session.getAttribute("username") displays the value, what if I completely want it to be unrepresented on that screen? That is why I was trying to work with hidden input values

Comment: @Sheogora: Then remove `session.getAttribute("username")%>` and use it only when you want username value.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer! I updates my question. I am using SessionAttributes and in the controller I am saving parameters as I go in an object and then during the third screen I just retrieve them :) I dont know if this is the politically correct way... but it seems to work pretty well, I also now have room to do parameters management during every screen step!

Answer (score 0):

I have done a "wizard-style" form like this before.  My solution used a single form bean that we put into session for the entire process, and included only the pieces in each page that needs to be added.  Spring will not erase a value in the form bean unless you include an input for the given value.  We don't use JSR-303, and I don't think this method would work if you are using it.  Our validation uses a combination of BindingErrors and custom validation code, so I just setup the code to only validate portions at a time, corresponding to what page the form just submitted.

Comment: Please check the updated code I did using SessionAttributes. I am still having problem passing the value filled in on the first screen to the third without referencing it again on the second screen. Thank you,

Comment: If you put a break point in processUserContact, is the value you are trying to get on the 3rd form set properly?  The only difference I see in your code from mine is that I used a bean to move the data between the forms.

Comment: I added several system.out.prints around the code, to check what data was passed and during the processUserContact the username is printed to be "NULL" when the line <form:input type="hidden" id="username" path="username"/> is removed from AddUserContact.jsp (EDIt sorry just noticed it said Ass in my code)

Comment: Change that to <form:hidden path="username"/>.  I don't think you can pass in a type to the <form:input>, or at least I didn't think you could.

Comment: do you know how I could avoid using username on the second screen without it being reset to null after the second screen form is filled?

Comment: Again, it "should" work such that if you have an input on form 1, and do not have it on form 2, then the value does not get set.  Spring, at least in my experience, does not over-write the values each time there is a submit.  Each transaction is automic, and will only include the values you submit to the Controller.  Every experience I have had with Spring MVC has reinforced this.  If you are saying the username is getting wiped if if you leave username off the 2nd form, then my intuition says something else is overwriting it or something is wrong with the value in session (perhaps the scope?)

Comment: Hello, dont know if this is relevant anymore, but my intiall thought of what was overwriting it is the fact that I was using class user as commandName during the second and first forms, so I thought it was creating that object again for the particular instance. I think I was asking earlier about that and if creating 2 clases for form 1 and 2 will fix it

Comment: Adding a value's attribute name to the SessionAttribute instructs Spring to maintain that value in session.  So, in essence, adding something to the Model will also add it to Session.  Thus, once its there, its there.  When you retrieve it from Model, or using the ModelAttribute annotation on your method parameters, Spring knows that this is the one in Session and uses that one.  So, at all 3 steps you should be able to manipulate the session object and be assured you are using the one from Session.